# How to get user input into a number triangle

Tags: java, loops, nested

So I am trying to make a number triangle that gets a user input and creates the triangle from that point. I was able to create the triangle I want to use (at least the format), but I am having trouble integrating user input into the code.

So far I have:

```
    for (int line = 1; line <= 9; line++)
    {
        for (int i =- 1 * line + 9; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= line; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(line);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Which outputs:

```
        1
       22
      333
     4444
    55555
   666666
  7777777
 88888888
999999999
```

How do I get the output to look something like this:

```
    1 // for any input n
   21
  321
```

Thank you!

Comment: What specifically about "integrating user input into the code" are you having problems with? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953302/how-to-enter-two-numbers-and-print-out-the-numbers-in-between-in-java

Comment: So far I have used the Scanner class and have assigned a variable to the users input. When I have tried to implement the user input inside of the loop, I've run into some syntax errors and infinite loops (new to java, still making my way around using correct syntax).

Comment: @AndroidCoder This seems to answer my question about the user input. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the second loop to this :

```
int n = 3; // You can use any number here in your case it is 3

for (int line = 1; line <= n; line++) {
    for (int i = - 1 * line + n; i >= 1; i--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------
    for (int j = line; j >= 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs

```
  1
 21
321
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers one of my questions.

Comment: what answer and what not answer @Ricta ?

Comment: Solved my format issue with my first input showing "55555" instead of "54321". Still wondering how I can get a user input into the loop. Example: user enters 3, output would be "1" "21" "321" in the triangle format.

Comment: @Ricta you can use a simple Scanner to read the input for example `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); int n = scan.nextInt();`

Comment: This answers my second question :) thanks so much!